# How to change DataFrame's rows to columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Now, I have a dataframe `df`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['a','a','b'], 'value1':[100,200,300], 'value2':[1,2,3]})
>>> df
  name  value1  value2
0    a     100       1
1    a     200       2
2    b     300       3
```

Now, I want to change `df` to following form:

```
        name  value1  value2 name  value1  value2
          a     100       1    a     200       2
          b     300       3
```

So, how can I convert `df` efficiently?

Comment: Your requested data structure doesn't look efficient for further processing (especially with duplicate headers). Why do you want it in that format? If there were dozens of the same name, you'd have potentially hundreds of columns. Maybe there's a better solution to get you your final result.

Comment: Thx, because I'm trying to process data to the form which my downstream need, I also think this structure is not well organized, but I have no other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
g = df.groupby('name').cumcount().astype(str)
df1 = (df.set_index([df['name'],g])
         .unstack()
         .sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
         .reset_index(drop=True))
```

For unique columns names use `join`:

```
df1.columns = df1.columns.map('_'.join)
print (df1)
  name_0  value1_0  value2_0 name_1  value1_1  value2_1
0      a     100.0       1.0      a     200.0       2.0
1      b     300.0       3.0   None       NaN       NaN
```

If want duplicate columns names use [`droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html):

```
df1.columns = df1.columns.droplevel(1)
print (df1)
  name  value1  value2  name  value1  value2
0    a   100.0     1.0     a   200.0     2.0
1    b   300.0     3.0  None     NaN     NaN
```

EDIT:

Alternative with `apply` is problematic, because all `dtypes` are changed to `object`.